# jquery: convert textarea (separated by new lines) to select option menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

this the     [demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1xqutsjk/)

I have tried this :

```js
$('.generate').click(function () {
    $('.inthis').text('<select class="select" id="' + $('.select-menu').val() + '"><option>' + $('.text-area').val().split('\n') + '</option><option>' + $('.text-area').val().split('\n') + '</option><option>' + $('.text-area').val().split('\n') + '</option></select>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="Text1" type="text" value="option_one" class="select-menu">
<br>
<textarea class="text-area" name="Text2" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="enter one wdg in one line">green
yellow
blue</textarea>
<br>
<input class="generate" type="button" value="test" />
<br>
<br>
<div class="inthis"></div>
```

but it did not work.

I want to be like this :

```
<select class="select" id="option_one">
<option>green</option>
<option>yellow</option>
<option>blue</option>
</select>
```

Comment: use `.html()` not `.text()`

Comment: .text() render as a plain text. Use .html() bcoz you need to display HTML elements.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1xqutsjk/1/ - user .html() as it render html elements

Comment: Taking away an accepted answer by adding your own is a pretty scummy thing to do - especially when the answer you added follows similar logic to those already added, but doesn't actually work at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this one:

```js
$('.generate').click(function () {
 var options = $('.text-area').val().split('\n').map(function(value) {
    return '<option>' + value + '</option>';
  });
    $('.inthis').text('<select class="select" id="' + $('.select-menu').val() + '">' + options.join('') + '</select>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="Text1" type="text" value="option_one" class="select-menu">
<br>
<textarea class="text-area" name="Text2" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="enter one wdg in one line">green
yellow
blue</textarea>
<br>
<input class="generate" type="button" value="test" />
<br>
<br>
<div class="inthis"></div>
```

Comment: Where is the added value here over the other identical solutions that DO work?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.generate').click(function() {

var options = $('.text-area').val().split('\n')

  $('.inthis').html('<select class="select" id="' + $('.select-menu').val() + '"><option>' + options[0] + '</option><option>' +  options[1] + '</option><option>' +  options[2] + '</option></select>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="Text1" type="text" value="option_one" class="select-menu">
<br>
<textarea class="text-area" name="Text2" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="enter one wdg in one line">green
yellow
blue</textarea>
<br>
<input class="generate" type="button" value="test" />
<br>
<br>
<div class="inthis"></div>
```

use `.html()`
not `.text()`

Comment: Not for my satisfaction but for subsequent visitors who may not understand why this answer was accepted

Comment: What if there are more than 3 options or empty lines?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, using `text()` will set the textual value of the element. If you want to create a new element within it then you can use `html()`, or `append()`, or any of jQuery's other DOM manipulation methods. In the example below I used `appendTo()` so I can maintain a reference to the `select` that was added.

From there you can `split()` the `textarea` value by each line *and then* loop through that array to build each lines' value as its own `option`. Try this:

```js
$('.generate').click(function() {
  var $select = $('<select class="select" id="' + $('.select-menu').val() + '" />').appendTo('.inthis');
  
  var options = $('.text-area').val().split('\n').map(function(value) {
    return '<option>' + value + '</option>';
  });
  $select.html(options.join(''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="Text1" type="text" value="option_one" class="select-menu">
<br>
<textarea class="text-area" name="Text2" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="enter one wdg in one line">green
yellow
blue</textarea><br>
<input class="generate" type="button" value="test" /><br><br>
<div class="inthis"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Text is as the name suggest not working for html or jQuery objects.

I am using the jQuery syntax on creating the objects and ignoring empty lines in the textarea

```js
$('.generate').on("click", function() {
  var $sel = $('<select />', {
      "class": "select",
      "id": $('.select-menu').val()
    }),
    opts = $('.text-area').val().split('\n').map(
      function(val) {
        if (val) return $('<option/>', {
          "value": val,
          "text": val
        });
      });
  $sel.append(opts);
  $('.inthis').html($sel);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="Text1" type="text" value="option_one" class="select-menu">
<br>
<textarea class="text-area" name="Text2" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="enter one wdg in one line">green
yellow

blue</textarea>
<br>
<input class="generate" type="button" value="test" />
<br>
<br>
<div class="inthis"></div>
```