# jquery convert textarea to dropdown

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, textarea

I have the following html codes:

```
<div class="notesrow" id="notesrow_8">
<label for="holdnotes_8">Reservation notes:</label>
<textarea id="holdnotes_8" rows="2" cols="30" name="notes_8"></textarea></div>
```

I want to convert into a select dropdown, with the following values:

```
For pick-up
For scanning
For courier
```

I am looking into this [jquery: convert textarea (separated by new lines) to select option menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42505629/jquery-convert-textarea-separated-by-new-lines-to-select-option-menu) but can't seem to make it work for my use case.

The code I am trying is below:

```
$('[id^=holdnotes_]').html('<select name="resnote" id="resnote" form="resnoteform"><option value="For Scanning">For Scanning</option> <option value="For Pick-up">For Pick-up</option>   <option value="For courier">For Courier</option></select>');
```

Problem is that the text is just being put inside the textarea? How do I convert my text area into a dropdown select list using jquery?

Answer (score 1):

[.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/) method inserts the specified content as the last child of each element in the jQuery collection.

[.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/) could get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the value of every matched element.

```js
$('[id^=holdnotes_]').html('<select name="resnote" id="resnote" form="resnoteform"><option value="For Scanning">For Scanning</option> <option value="For Pick-up">For Pick-up</option>   <option value="For courier">For Courier</option></select>');

$('#notesrow_8').append($('#holdnotes_8').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="notesrow" id="notesrow_8">
  <label for="holdnotes_8">Reservation notes:</label>
  <textarea id="holdnotes_8" rows="2" cols="30" name="notes_8"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, works as advertise. But I forgot to mention that whatever is put in the textarea should also be sent into the form. That I need to figure out how to do.